# Gerar chave para acessar documento

Tags: java, algoritmo, random

Preciso gerar uma chave que contenha letras e números Ex: "AJ67G8". estou gerando com o Random do java.io.Serializable:

```
public static String nomeAleatorio(int nCaracteres) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    char[] letras = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".toCharArray();

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i <= nCaracteres; i++) {
        int ch = rand.nextInt(letras.length);
        sb.append(letras[ch]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Essa chave tem que ser única, o problema é que o Ramdom não garante isso e ficar indo ao banco cada vez pra verificar se a chave existe é muito trabalhoso. Qual estratégia usar para resolver esse problema?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=+fisher-yates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O jeito mais fácil de resolver isso seria com o [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) (Identificador Único Universal) que é representado por valor de 128 bits.

Você pode gerar um com o seguinte trecho de código:

```
private String geraChaveUnica()
{
    final String idUnico = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
    return idUnico;
}
```

Output:

```
feefa833f1184bd3bfa44272bea74a75
```